# Flutter generate Freezed files for Cubit with build_runner not working

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-freezed

I am trying to use the [Freezed Package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) together with the `Cubits` from the [Bloc Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApvMmTrBaFI&t=742s) and I want to simply create Cubits with Freezed but I can not make it work.

Calling:

`flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

does not create anything.

Here is my setup:

**`courses_cubit.dart`:**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'courses_state.dart';
part 'courses_cubit.freezed.dart';

class CoursesCubit extends Cubit<CoursesState> {
  CoursesCubit() : super(CoursesState.initial());
}
```

**`courses_state.dart`:**

```
part of 'courses_cubit.dart';

@freezed
class CoursesState with _$CoursesState {
  const factory CoursesState.initial() = _Initial;
}
```

According to the Tutorial and also [this article](https://hedighodhbane08.medium.com/flutter-cubit-freezed-a-great-combination-for-state-management-9f94bc4fbcc5) running the command above should create the file `courses_cubit_freezed.dart`. But like I said, nothing happens. The command runs successfully with no changes.

What am I missing here? Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess something was messed up with my `cache`or sth. Removing all the packages and installing it like this solved the issue:

**Bloc**

> `flutter pub add flutter_bloc`

**Freezed**

> `flutter pub add freezed_annotation`
>
> `flutter pub add --dev build_runner`
>
> `flutter pub add --dev freezed`

after installing it simply run this to generate the missing file:

> `flutter pub run build_runner build`